# How to remove routes depending the object Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I would like to remove the delete route for certain objects (which are linked to others...).

Is there a way to remove Routes in the configureRoutes method depending on the edited object (for example the id)?

Or is there a way to do it in the configureFormFields method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: This is a very old answer, so it may or may not work in your case**

To get the current object inside XXXAdmin class use:

`$this->getSubject();`

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
  $product = $this->getSubject();

  if ($product->getId()) { // editing
    //
  }
  //...
}

public function configureRoutes(\Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection $collection)  {
  $product = $this->getSubject();

  if ($product->getId()) { // editing
    $collection->remove('route');
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it do not work (and I don't know why btw).
_Call to a member function getId() on a non-object_

Comment: And for the details I tried something like :
'if($this->hasSubject()) {
            $collection
                ->remove('delete')
            ;
 }'
And hasSubject always return false even if I'm in an editing form.

Comment: If you dont have a Id in your entity, it will not work, you have to use a entity field that must be required to fill when it's created

Comment: The problem was that I have to check if there is a Subject before getting the entity's id.